# How to specify a password on the command line of an SSIS package run

Tags: configuration, ssis

I am having an issue where I need to be able to specify the password when I run my packages.

This article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760 says:

---

**Method 3: Set the SSIS Package ProtectionLevel property to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword**
Change the SSIS Package ProtectionLevel property to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. This setting uses a password for encryption. You can then modify the SQL Server Agent job step command line to include this password.

---

That all sounds well and good.  But where and how to you specify the password?

Here is an example of my current command line:

```
/FILE "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages
       \MainSSISPackage.dtsx"  /CONFIGFILE "C:\Program Files
       \Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages\DataConfig.dtsConfig"
        /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about this?

```
/De[crypt] password
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: remember to enter the password as is and without any enclosing single or double quotation marks.

Comment: also remember that on the SQL Agent Steps - Command Line tab for SSIS execution , there is simple a manual edit radio button which enables you to enter your password in front of /Decrypt parameter.

Comment: The password added to command line of the step manually is not saved at all. Is there any way to save it?

Answer (score 1):

```
/FILE "\"E:\SSIS\New folder\test\test\Package.dtsx\"" /DECRYPT  password /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING E
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a ten year old question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

Try dtexec option

```
/P[assword]password
```